# Sql insert System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

i have a problem i can not see it

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=True";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into User(Username,Password,Firstname,Lastname,Email) VALUES(@user,@pass,@fname,@lname,@emai)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", TxtUserN.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtpass.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emai", TxtEmail.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("You are registered");
```

I get a error saying that i have

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'User'.

My db is

```
[ID]
      ,[Username]
      ,[Password]
      ,[Firstname]
      ,[Lastname]
      ,[Email]
  FROM [MyDb].[dbo].[User]
```

Comment: what is your Table name?

Comment: Have you tried catching the thrown exception to see more details?

Comment: @jannagy02 problem is that user is reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

`User` is a keyword, needs to be quoted:

```
insert into [User] (Username,Password,Firstname,Lastname,Email) VALUES(@user,@pass,@fname,@lname,@emai)
```

Also, never store passwords in clear. Use a [salted cryptographic hash](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure).

Comment: Thanks for you're help and yeah i will look in to salted cryptographic hash this was just a start on it

Answer (score 0):

User is the reserved keyword in SQL so try query like:

```
insert into [User] (Username,Password,Firstname,Lastname,Email) 
VALUES(@user,@pass,@fname,@lname,@emai)
```

Here is list of reserved keywords in sql => [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)